# Is it a bad practice to create a generic wrapper over Core Data models?

Tags: ios, swift, oop, generics, core-data

I'm studying Swift and Core Data and I plan to use a simple wrapper over it for my models.

At this point, protocol and extension looks like this:

```
protocol CRUD {
    associatedtype T: NSManagedObject

    var context: NSManagedObjectContext { get }

    var items: [T]! { get set }

    func getAll() -> [T]
    mutating func addOrUpdate(_ item: T) -> T
    mutating func delete(_ item: T)
}


extension CRUD where T: NSManagedObject {
    var context: NSManagedObjectContext {
        return (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    }

    func save() {
        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch {
            fatalError("Saving of \(String(describing: self)) failed")
        }
    }

    func getAll() -> [T] {
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<T>(entityName: String(describing: T.self))
        let list: [T]

        do {
            list = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
        } catch {
            fatalError("Fetching of \(String(describing: self)) failed")
        }

        return list
    }

    mutating func delete(_ item: T) {
        if let index = items.index(of: item) {
            items.remove(at: index)
        }

        context.delete(item)
        save()
    }

    mutating func addOrUpdate(_ item: T) -> T {
        if (items.contains(item)) {
            items.append(item)
        }

        save()
        return item
    }
}
```

And each model is declared like this:

```
class TaskModel : CRUD {
    typealias T = Task

    var items: [Task]! 

    init() {
        self.items = getAll()
    }
}
```

How much does this code correspond to the principles of OOP (in particular, can I call this protocol the implementation of the DAO pattern)? Are such wrappers needed? Or does Core Data imply the direct use of models in the code?

What possible problems can reveal with it in the future?

I will be very grateful for the advice from more experienced iOS developers. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5):

A protocol might be too much for this kind of functionality, as protocols main goal is still polymorphism. You could use a generic struct instead:

```
struct CRUD<T: NSManagedObject> {

    var context: NSManagedObjectContext {
        return (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    }

    var items = [T]()

    // let's provide two approaches for initialization
    init() {
        self.init(items: getAll())
    }

    init(items: [T]) {
        self.items = items
    }

    func save() {
        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch {
            fatalError("Saving of \(String(describing: self)) failed")
        }
    }

    func getAll() -> [T] {
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<T>(entityName: String(describing: T.self))
        let list: [T]

        do {
            list = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
        } catch {
            fatalError("Fetching of \(String(describing: self)) failed")
        }

        return list
    }

    mutating func delete(_ item: T) {
        if let index = items.index(of: item) {
            items.remove(at: index)
        }

        context.delete(item)
        save()
    }

    mutating func addOrUpdate(_ item: T) -> T {
        if (items.contains(item)) {
            items.append(item)
        }

        save()
        return item
    }
}
```

You can then use it in your class:

```
class TaskModel {
    // making sure no-one from outside can mutate our CRUD
    private(set) lazy var crud = CRUD<Task>()

    init() {
        // nothing to do here, the items are already populated
    }
}

let model = TaskModel()
// the following won't compile
model.crud.delete(someTask)
```

IMO, this better transmit the intent of having a Facade over CoreData.